# Chinese bibliography in reference, instead of display "等", it displayed "çŋĽ"

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, templates

I wrote a paper using the Elegantpaper v0.08 template. And cite some Chinese bibliography.
After compiling the file, I found something wrong in my PDF.
The "等" in the reference shows wrong, it displayed as "çŋĽ".

My tex file is like this.

```latex
\documentclass[lang=cn, a4paper, 12pt]{elegantpaper}
\title{test file}
\author{Direct-A}
\date{\today}
\version{0.1}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
test\cite{RN1}

\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

And the bib file

```latex
@article{RN1,
  author  = {张麻子 and 李四 and 王五 and 张三},
  title   = {我就是马邦德},
  journal = {让子弹飞},
  volume  = {1},
  number  = {23},
  pages   = {210-220},
  issn    = {1007-4368},
  doi     = {10.1016/rzdf001011},
  year    = {2013},
  type    = {Journal Article}
}
```

I used `MiKTex 2.9`, `Visual Studio Code 1.41.1` as a editer and `LaTeX Workshop 8.7.1` as a extension.
Compile: XeLaTeX => BibTeX => XeLaTeX => XeLaTeX

Comment: Is the absence of the correct glyph the only issue in the pdf file?

Comment: @Mico Yes, it's the only problem in the whole pdf file.

Comment: Do please provide more information about your document setup. I'm afraid that you haven't provided nearly enough information so far to let anyone form a diagnosis, let alone come up with a cure. Please edit your posting to provide supplemental information about the TeX distribution you use, the document class you employ, the TeX engine you use, and how the bibliography is being constructed. E.g., do you use a software tool such as BibTeX or biblatex?

Comment: @MicoThanks. I've complate the other info.

Comment: I get the expected result.

Comment: I don't have the fonts but add \XeTeXtracingfonts=1 and check in the log-file which fonts are used. Then compile on a terminal with `xelatex --output-driver="xdvipdfmx -vv" file` and check if the same fonts are used by xdvipdfmx.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer after I add `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` I find `LaTeX Font Warning: Font  hape 'TU/SimSun(0)/bx/n' undefined (Font) using 'TU/SimSun(0)/m/n' instead on input line 1.` I've installed this font but it still there. How to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that problem, thanks for  @Ulrike Fischer and thanks for everyone help me.

After add `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` in .tex file, I checked the log file.

And I find this:

```
Requested font "SimSun/OT" at 11.99997pt
 -> C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/simsun.ttc
Requested font "SimSun/OT" at 12.00003pt
 -> C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/simsun.ttc
Requested font "KaiTi/OT:script=hani;language=dflt;" at 12.00002pt
 -> C:/Users/****/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts/KaiTi.ttf
Requested font "KaiTi/B/OT:script=hani;language=dflt;" at 12.00002pt
 -> C:/Users/****/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts/KaiTi.ttf

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "KaiTi/B" (it probably doesn't
(fontspec)             exist).

Requested font "SimHei/OT:script=hani;language=dflt;" at 12.00002pt
 -> C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/simhei.ttf
Requested font "SimHei/I/OT:script=hani;language=dflt;" at 12.00002pt
 -> C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/simhei.ttf

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "SimHei/I" (it probably doesn't
(fontspec)             exist).

Requested font "SimSun/OT:script=hani;language=dflt;" at 12.00002pt
 -> C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/simsun.ttc
Requested font "SimSun/BI/OT:script=hani;language=dflt;" at 12.00002pt
 -> C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/simsun.ttc

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "SimSun/BI" (it probably doesn't
(fontspec)             exist).

Requested font "SimSun/OT:script=hani;language=dflt;" at 12.00003pt
 -> C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/simsun.ttc
Requested font "SimHei/OT:script=hani;language=dflt;" at 12.00003pt
 -> C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/simhei.ttf
Requested font "KaiTi/OT:script=hani;language=dflt;" at 12.00003pt
 -> C:/Users/****/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts/KaiTi.ttf

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'SimSun(0)' created for font 'SimSun' with
(fontspec)             options
(fontspec)             [Script={CJK},BoldFont={SimHei},ItalicFont={KaiTi}].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"SimSun/OT:script=hani;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"SimHei/OT:script=hani;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"KaiTi/OT:script=hani;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.: 

 (test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
```

Moreover, I've got a warning in `VS code`.

```
Font shape `TU/SimSun(0)/bx/n' undefined
(Font)  using `TU/SimSun(0)/m/n' instead.
```

Okey, problem changes.

**Finally I changed the environment to `TeXLive`(full scheme), it solved.**